# Meaning of notch?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, american-english

I'm quite a bit confused about the meaning of this word. I remember searching up this word or having seen something that indicates that "notch/notches" are marks (for example, the marks that are around a radio button that serve as indicators for how high or how low the volume is and etc...), but when I look up the meaning it doesn't say anything about it besides the meaning of "dent" or something completely unrelated to what I thought.

I also know that notch means the part where the camera is built in on a smartphone. So I already got that.

And

I also know the meaning of the phrase "let's kick it up a notch".

But I don't know what it really is....!!!!!!

Does it mean marks? Like I previously stated  (like on a burner or a radio).

My brain is on fire.

Answer (score 5):

You might try a different dictionary:

> **[notch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/notch)** (n):
>   1. An indentation or incision on an edge or surface.
>     1.2 A nick made on something in order to keep a score or record.
>     1.3 A point or degree in a scale.
>
> **notch** (v):
>   1. Make notches in.
>   2. Score or achieve (something).

"Let's kick it up a notch" relates to *noun* definition *1.3*.  It suggests that, on some metaphorical scale of excitement/enjoyment, we should take it *one step higher*.

Otherwise, a "notch" is just a mark or indentation in anything.  It doesn't have to be for any particular purpose:

> The bored student cut **notches** in his desk as a way to pass the time.

Alternately, you can purposefully carve notches to do something like keep count:

> The prideful gunslinger carved a **notch** in the handle of his revolver each time he won a shootout.

Because notches are usually *narrow*, it doesn't really make sense to use it to refer to how the camera is built into a smartphone.  It's possible, but I would prefer something like "aperture" or "slot".